# How to synchronise Drupal users with CiviCRM organisations

Tags: drupal

I was trying to set contacts added by the synchronisation between Drupal users and CiviCRM contacts as an organisation contact not as an individual. But I can't find where to do so.
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm not sure you can Anis. It maybe useful to edit to your question to give a little more context and perhaps others can make suggests for other ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: Actually i need this because i am using civicase and i want to attach organisation contacts as roles in the case. That's why i want to create users where its contact type in CiviCRM is organisation not individual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  think it is reasonable to give an organisation a Drupal account. After all, an organisation can also have an email address and a phone number. But I tried to create an organisation-Drupal account combination from the interface on a CiviCRM 4.7.15, but I did not succeed. I tried the following scenario.

- I created an organisation with an email address.
- I created a Drupal user with the same email address.

Result: two contacts in CiviCRM, an Indiviual and an Organization.

But under the hood, using SQL, you have more options.

- Insert or update the connection record in the table `civicrm_uf_match`.
- Update in SQL the type of a contact (the column is `contact_type`) from *Individual* to *Organization*.

I tried this and the Contact View looks fine, and the record is not duplicated when I run the *synchronize users* job. This suggests that you can do this for a small set with some SQL manipulation, and for a large set you can create an extension.

Comment: If you don't have anyone comfortable implementing an SQL change like this for whatever reason I think you can set this up with views bulk operations and rules - but it's likely to be more difficult and time consuming than the more elegant solution posted above :)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It solved my problem. But it looks weird that there is no solution except using SQL.

Comment: Hm, when someone logs in into the system, it is always a person. So there exists an individual, and from CiviCRM's point of view, it makes sense to register the details of this contact. And if this contact is related to an organisation, create a relationship. But I can imagine that if you combine this with CiviCase, it becomes complicated.

Comment: In general I think it is better to sync users with individuals. As you say a user has to be a person. An organisation can't log in. Only a person at the organisation can log in.